# How to use the same variable name with let when calling defmacro?

Tags: elisp-macros, macroexpansion, defmacro

This is only an example, I understand this can easily be achieved with a function.

**Don't Work**

---

This is what I've come up with based on the elisp manual and a couple of answers/articles that I have read. The suggestion is to use `gensym`, but I can't get it to output `'("bread")`, instead I get `'(g719)`.

```lisp
(defmacro shop (item)
  (let ((var (gensym)))
   `(let ((,var ,item ))
      (add-to-list 'shopping-list '(,var)))))

(let ((item "bread"))
     (macroexpand '(shop item)))
```

RESULTS:

```lisp
(let
    ((g719 item))
  (add-to-list 'shopping-list
               '(g719)))
```

**Works but...**

---

This works when I rename the variable from `item` to `my-item`, but I would like to use
the same name. I've read you're not suppose to use eval. Not sure about symbol-value?

```lisp
(defmacro shop (item)
`(add-to-list 'shopping-list '(,(symbol-value item))))

(let ((my-item "bread"))
     (macroexpand '(shop my-item)))
```

RESULTS:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'shopping-list
             '("bread"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the macro expansion again:

```lisp
(let
    ((g719 item))
  (add-to-list 'shopping-list
               '(g719)))
```

Notice how `g719` is inside of a quoted list? It won’t be evaluated there, because it is quoted. Write your macro like this instead:

```
(defmacro shop (item)
  (let ((var (gensym)))
   `(let ((,var ,item ))
      (add-to-list 'shopping-list (list ,var)))))
```

By writing it as a call to the `list` function, you ensure that the arguments to that call will be evaluated first, and then the value is put into the list instead of the name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I copied your code and it does not work. The only difference is it expands to `(list g719)` instead of `'("bread")`.

Comment: That’s what it’s supposed to do. `macroexpand` doesn’t evaluate anything; that happens later.

Comment: Sorry about that, you're right. So I noticed that with your answer, I don't even need all the `let` in the macro or `gensym` huh? Because it works the same like this in the macro: `(backquote (add-to-list 'shopping-list (list ,item)))`

Comment: Yes. Just be aware that directly substituting an argument multiple times will cause it to be evaluated multiple times. That’s when you need to start using `let` to collect the value once, and once you do that you want to use `gensym` in order to avoid shadowing a name that might be in use inside an expression given to you by the caller.

Comment: What do you mean by `substituting an argument multiple times`? Do you mean using a comma to sub/evaluate?

Comment: Yes, `,foo` substitutes the expression into your backquoted code. Doing that multiple times is generally a bad idea. It doesn’t matter at all if the expression is just `"bread"`, but if it is more complicated than that then it’ll cause annoying problems.

Comment: Gotcha, I would have to put it to the test sometime to understand it more with a function as an argument that increments or changes variables.